# C# Foreground / Background TemplateBinding not applied on initial setter but within trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, templatebinding

I'm trying to set the foreground of a TextBlock within a custom control within an initial setter, but the color remains default. The strange thing is doing it within a Trigger it works just fine.

I also added TemplateBinding to the TextBlock.Foreground property within the custom control but it doesn't make a difference.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<controls:NavigationDrawer
    Grid.Column="0"
    Background="#212121"
    IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbToggleNavigationDrawer}"
    OpenCloseDuration="0:0:0.25">

    <controls:NavigationDrawer.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="controls:NavigationDrawerItem">
            <!-- does not work -->
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="ImageSize" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                    <!-- works perfectly fine -->
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </controls:NavigationDrawer.Resources>

    <controls:NavigationDrawer.Content>
        <StackPanel Margin="10,10">
            <controls:NavigationDrawerItem Content="Home" ImageSource="/Resources/home-white.png" />
            <controls:NavigationDrawerItem Content="Launchers" ImageSource="/Resources/launcher-white.png" />
            <controls:NavigationDrawerItem Content="Games" ImageSource="/Resources/game-white.png" />
            <controls:NavigationDrawerItem Content="Contribute" ImageSource="/Resources/contribute-white.png" />
            <controls:NavigationDrawerItem Content="About" ImageSource="/Resources/about-white.png" />
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:NavigationDrawer.Content>
</controls:NavigationDrawer>
```

NavigationDrawerItemStyle.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationDrawerItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationDrawerItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Viewbox
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding ImageSize}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding ImageSize}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ImageSource}" />
                    </Viewbox>

                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                    <!--  
                    Does not make a difference to add 
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    to TextBlock
                    -->

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

That's how it looks like after starting the app:

[image: Foreground not applied]

Comment: What happens if you remove the ``Trigger`` block?

Comment: No difference the Text Foreground remains black

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the trigger to the `ControlTemplate` and set the `Foreground` property of the `TextBlock` directly:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationDrawerItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Viewbox
            Grid.Column="0"
            Width="{TemplateBinding ImageSize}"
            Height="{TemplateBinding ImageSize}">
            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ImageSource}" />
        </Viewbox>

        <TextBlock x:Name="tb"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="White"
            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If this doesn't work, you are probably setting the `Foreground` property somewhere else in your code.

Comment: In general it would work but not in my use case as the IsSelected Property is a property of a control on the main window